# Calculating days between dates in Python?

Tags: python

Got set some course homework to do this. It was going all good until I noticed one of the test cases werent working, trying to get the days between `2012-1-1` and `2013-1-1`.

I guessed it would be 366, extra day as `2012` was a leap year. This code seems to be guessing 365, my tutor has marked the answer down as 360.

He said something about "just make all months 30 days", so I'm thinking his `360` is something related to that? Anyway, that doesn't excuse my code guessing `365` when it should be guessing `366`.

Output is as shows

> Test case passed! CONGRATULATIONS
>   Test with data: (2012, 1, 1, 2013, 1, 1) failed passed 365 should of passed 360
>   Test case passed! CONGRATULATIONS

```
daysOfMonths = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ] 

def is_leap_year(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

def get_days_from_year(year):
    days = year * 365
    i = 0

    while i < year:
        i += 1
        if is_leap_year(i):
            days += 1

    return days

def get_days_from_month(month, year):
    days = 0
    i = 0

    while i < month:
        if i == 1 and is_leap_year(year):
            days += daysOfMonths[i] + 1
        else:
            days += daysOfMonths[i]
        i += 1

    return days

def get_days_from_date(year, month, day): 
    days_in_year = get_days_from_year(year)
    days_in_month = get_days_from_month(month - 1, year)
    days = days_in_year + days_in_month + day
    return days

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    first_date_days = get_days_from_date(year1, month1, day1)
    second_date_days = get_days_from_date(year2, month2, day2)


    if first_date_days > second_date_days:
        return first_date_days - second_date_days
    else:
        return second_date_days - first_date_days

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,9,30,2012,10,30),30), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2013,1,1),360),
                  ((2012,9,1,2012,9,4),3)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print("Test with data:", args, "failed passed", result, "should of passed", answer)
        else:
            print("Test case passed! CONGRATULATIONS")

test()
```

Comment: Write a test for every function you call and find the one that is returning something different than what you'd expect. Alternatively, use a debugger to step through your calculation.

Comment: This is not related to the problem but it should have been "should have", not "should of".

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing **i** in the wrong place.  You have:

```
while i < year:
    i += 1
    if is_leap_year(i):
        days += 1
```

but should be:

```
while i < year:
    if is_leap_year(i):
        days += 1
    i += 1
```

because of this, your leap years are all off by 1 (2011 vs 2012, 2015 vs 2016, etc.)

Comment: so all months have 30 days except february in a leap year?

Comment: No.  It's just that February has an extra day in a leap year...29 vs 28. - The expectation of 360 seems wrong to me, as it does to the OP.  Making the change I mention gives the OP the result he expects...366.

Comment: if you want the real value just use `(datetime.datetime(Y,M,D) - datetime.datetime(Y1,M1,D1)).days`

Comment: @Joran, I think he has to do this without any special date functions.  It's a homework assignment that has that provision, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

He said something about **"just make all months 30 days"**, so

```
def get_range(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2):
    """
    assumes all months have 30 days, with no leap years
    ~ for some weird reason i dont understand
   (probably so you dont use builtin datetime)

    """
    days_difference = (year2-year1)*360
    days_difference += (month2-month1)*30
    return days_difference + day2-day1


print(get_range(2012, 1, 1, 2013, 1, 1))
```

if you want to get the actual number of days between two dates

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_real_range(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2):
    return (datetime(year2,month2,day2) - datetime(year1,month1,day1)).days
```